# AngualrJS - Module - Controller Access Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue communicating from my application to a module i have created. I have create an AngularJS module below.

```
(function (document, window) {

    'use strict';

    var piCart = angular.module('piCart', []);

    piCart.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.
            when('/cart', {
                templateUrl: "packages/pi-cart/segments/cart.html",
                controller: 'CartController',
                private : true
            }).
            when('/checkout', {
                template: "Checkout Page",
               // controller: 'CartController',
                private : true
            });
    }]);

    piCart.factory('TestFactory', function(){
        return{
            test : function(){
                return 'test works';
            }
        }
    });

    piCart.controller("CartController",function(TestFactory){
        console.log("Cart Controller Running");
        console.log(TestFactory.test());
    });

})(document, window);
```

This is loaded into my main application as so

`var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', "ui.bootstrap", "googlechart", "piCart"]);`

Im trying to call the module TestFactory from the app.controller like so

```
app.controller('ProductController',function($scope){

  $scope.addToCart = function(id){
    //alert("clicked: "+id);
    test = TestFactory.test();
    console.log(test);
  };

});
```

But im getting the error
`ReferenceError: TestFactory is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're getting that error because you did not inject TestFactory in the controller:

```
app.controller('ProductController', function($scope, TestFactory) {
    // your code...
});
```